# How to change the user's username in login in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

everyone.

When a user logs into the system, I want their user name to be left with lowercase characters. But in the database there is a user with the name in uppercase, so the login fails. Is there a way to get database data in lowercase letters before login validation?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example and clarify *get database data in lowercase letters before login validation*?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `strtolower()` when saving the username inside your database.

Same thing when you try to query the table.

In other words, you should remove the responsibility of *decorating* the username field from the database